# c# removing item from listbox then it will deduct the value from the textbox

Tags: c#

after i delete an item to the listbox it will also deduct the value from the textbox.
here's my code.

```
private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int total1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtTotal.Text);


        if (listBox1.Text =="item1 600")
        {

            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
            total1 -= 600;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your actual problem?

Comment: `txtTotal.Text = total1.ToString();`

Comment: umm, i only want to delete the item on the listbox and it will deduct the value from the textbox.

Comment: you want to delete only if doubled clicked value is "item1 600"?

Comment: yes @NicoRiff then it will deduct the value from the textbox

Comment: assuming the textbox holds he same value that was totaled (total1) then what JohanP suggested was to update your textbox back to the result of total1-600.

Comment: my textbox has the result/string of 800 and it will deduct a value of 600 to it, but the return value from the textbox is zero. pls help xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work it will remove 600 from the total TextBox:

```
    private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int total1 = int.Parse(txtTotal.Text);

        if (listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() == "item1 600")
        {

            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
            total1 -= 600;

            txtTotal.Text = total1 + "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: dude i got an error from listbox1.selectedvalue.tostring() code but i changed it to listBox1.Text, it's okay now, Thank you!

Comment: No problem. You should probably mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably think about creating an object that holds the two pieces of information. With the object you could override the .ToString() method to only show Item1 and get the 600 from the non-viewed property.

Something like:

```
public class MyItem
{
   public string Text {get; set;}
   public string Amount {get; set;}

   public override string ToString()
   {
       return Text;
   }
}
```

Then you can instantiate a new object and set the Name and Amount properties and then add it to your listbox.

When you are about to remove your item, you can get the Amount from the object and subtract it from your total. This would alleviate you having to create an If statement for every item in your list. Which